# Iterate over boost graph without Visitor

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I need to iterate over a graph(DFS), but without using the standard DFS visitor callback technique.

Is there a way to iteratively traverse the graph in this manner ?

```
for(each edge in my graph visited in dfs) {
    do some complicated stuff;
}
```

Comment: wait, you want DFS but not DFS? Do you simply mean you don't like the BGL API?

Comment: Yes. I am integrating boost into some existing code and it would be much simpler if it worked this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, depending on the concrete graph type, you can just do

```
auto e = edges(g);
for (auto it = e.first; it != e.second; ++it)
{
}
```

You might want `in_edges(g)` or `out_edges(g)` if your graph models different concepts: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html

**Edit** Update to the comments:

You'll have to wrap it yourself then. You could force a pull interface using Boost Coroutine. Or you can use the visitor to fill a queue, which you consumer after the DFS completed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But how would I go about accessing the edges in DFS order ?

Comment: How is this DFS? It looks like it just iterates the edges in no particular order.

Comment: @pbible If you look at the conversation, you'll see I said exactly that. The answer is, the OP will have to write it himself, because BGL has no such API